# Apply with LinkedIn program no response

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I am willing to import linkedin full profile data of registered members of my website. so users of my website can just click a button and all their linkedin data like education/organization/jobs etc are imported to my site/database

I think I need to apply for the "Apply with LinkedIn program" after creating a linkedin application.

I did fill up the apply form here https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply but its been a month, I haven't got any reply from linkedin.

Do I need to do anything else or I can still import all data without a need of approvement from linkedin?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about LinkedIn's API policies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LinkedIn recently closed their API program and your best bet is to find someone at LinkedIN to speak with them directly.